# CPH airport (Copenhagen) covid test center?

Tags: covid-19, denmark, scandinavia, danish-residents

I am flying to Copenhagen airport (CPH) next week. I read that I have to present "proof of a negative COVID-19 test".

The airport itself has a test center as per https://www.cph.dk/en/practical/travel-safely-through-copenhagen-airport

Can I use the test center in the airport as proof?

Comment: The big question IMHO is whether there are any airlines who may refuse boarding unless you have a test at the origin airport...

Comment: I added a comment below, if I show that I can get tested in Copenhagen the airline should allow me to travel...

Comment: @Jcaron of course there might be airlines that refuse boarding if you don't have a test, but as long there is one airline (like SAS) that don't require it it is possible to fly without a test

Answer (score 4):

The [page](https://www.cph.dk/en/practical/travel-safely-through-copenhagen-airport) you link to is a little bit hard to read with all collapsed sections. In **"Where is the test centre located and what are the opening hours?"**

> The test center is located outside at parking P5

So you can't use the "test center" to pass border control.

In **"New requirements for persons from high-risk countries"**

> - A service provider has facilitated a test facility in Pier E and in Pier C, so that passengers arriving without a valid test result can be tested. This test can then be used for documentation at the border control.
> - We would strongly encourage passengers to have a Covid-19 test performed before arrival in CPH, so that there is as far as possible assurance that they are not infected on arrival in Denmark.
> - Passengers residing in a high-risk country that gets a positive test result in CPH will be handled by the authorities

So there is a rapid test available if you can't perform it before you go. It is not recommended though.

Comment: Well, why you think it's not recommended? I guess is better, otherwise a test that is 48hs old is not as reliable as one done directly there.... and there must be a reason the opened it before border

Comment: @Chicago1988 If I were you I would get a test before you fly. That way you avoid a) putting others at risk on the flight; b) the consequences of testing positive on arrival; c) the possibility that entry restrictions change between now and your flight date, such that a pre-arrival test becomes mandatory

Comment: 1. The last point I quoted "Passengers residing in a high-risk country that gets a positive test result in CPH will be handled by the authorities" isn't very detailed. Will you be locked in for 14 days somewhere?
2. I don't know about test capacity, lines and how crowded the area will be with a lot of people waiting for their test result.

Comment: @Chicago1988 Given the incubation period, no test is any indication that you are not infected anyway. But a test take before you board is still better because that reduces the chances of one potentially infected people during the flight. Also, rapid tests are usually even less accurate than the standard PCR tests.